# Ruby RestClient post request with cookies

Tags: ruby, api, rest-client

I've been trying for over a week now with no joy to post an api request setting the cookies with values from a previous request. First request is fine:

```
  response = RestClient.post ('http://api-qa1:8180/api/rest/GB/session'),'{"email":""}',:content_type => 'application/json'

obj = JSON.parse(response)
id = obj['id']
profileId = obj['profile_id']
@cookies = response.cookies
dyn = obj['verification_id']
jsessionid = @cookies['JSESSIONID']
puts jsessionid,dyn,profileID
```

I get a response and the values i need, I now want to use the values returned 'profile_id'(URi), jsessionid(cookie), and dyn(cookie) values to form my second request.

```
  res = RestClient.post ("http://api-qa1:8180/api/rest/GB/profile/#{profileId}/cart/item"),
                    '{
                              "sku_id":"1234"
                              "product_id":"1234"
                              "quantity":"2"
                              "recommended":"false"
                         }',
                    headers = {
                        :content_type => 'application/json',

                        :userPrefLanguage => 'en-GB'

                    }
cookies = {'JSESSIONID' => jsessionid},{'DYN_USER_CONFIRM' => dyn }
```

I've tried many combinations all to no avail, this is as far as i've got which gives me a 403, im also aware that post request should have a maximum of 3 arguments I just cant get it to work. The cookies properties i need to set are 
DYN_USER_CONFIRM and JSESSION.

Answer (score 3):

Just looking at the documentation for `RestClient`:

```
response.cookies
# => {"_applicatioN_session_id" => "1234"}

response2 = RestClient.post(
  'http://localhost:3000/',
  {:param1 => "foo"},
  {:cookies => {:session_id => "1234"}}
)
```

It looks like you need to set cookies and headers as a hash inside of the request. The code you've posted has `cookies = ....` and it's not inside of the request. You need to set headers in a hash as well I believe.

Comment: Please add a pointer to specific doc page you are referencing.